# my sql database connect to android

Tags: android

i am using eclipse and i want to connect MySQL database to my android application. i try some  coding which found on internet but no result is shown on emulator mobile device. even no any error is shown.  please reply me in step by step procedure to connect the my MySQL database.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

        TextView resultview;
        private InputStream is;

        @SuppressLint("NewApi")
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            resultview=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.resultview);
        }

        public void getData() {
           String result = "";
            //the year data to send
            ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name","suman"));

            //http post
            try {
                    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://localhost/hello/try.php");
                    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost); 
                    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                    is = entity.getContent();

                    Log.e("log_tag", "connection success ");
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "pass", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } catch(Exception e) {
                    Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Connection fail", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            //convert response to string
            try {
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    String line = null;
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                            sb.append(line + "\n");
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Input Reading pass", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    is.close();

                    result=sb.toString();
            } catch(Exception e) {
                   Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), " Input reading fail", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            //parse json data
            try {
                JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);

                for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
                       JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        Log.i("log_tag","id: "+json_data.getInt("id")+
                                ", Name: "+json_data.getString("name")+
                                ", Address: "+json_data.getInt("address")+
                                ", Contact: "+json_data.getInt("contact")
                        );
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "JsonArray pass", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               }
            } catch(JSONException e) {
                    Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "JsonArray fail", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
```

php script is:-

```
     <?php
   mysql_connect("localhost","root");
    mysql_select_db("test");

   $q=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_user");
   while($e=mysql_fetch_assoc($q))
    $output[]=$e;

  print(json_encode($output));

  mysql_close();
  ?>
```

Comment: did you add internet permission in menifest file.

Comment: yes i give the the internet permission

Comment: Have you tried debugging from httpclient.execute() ?

Comment: tell me onething from where you are calling getData().

Comment: i am calling data from mysql database(table:- tbl_user, database:- test)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to refer to the computer which is running the Android simulator, use the IP address `10.0.2.2` instead `localhost`. You can read more from [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#networkaddresses)

In your code change from

`http://localhost/hello/try.php`

to

`http://ip address/hello/try.php`